# How am I ending up with 5 threads when I only start 2?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to write a program that compares some data from output on routers to what we have in a database. In order to speed it up (there's a fair number of devices) I want to have it multi-threaded. If I only start 2 threads I would think I should have 3 threads. The main thread and the two workers. But for some reason I end up with 5 threads which then goes down to 3 threads but never lower than 3 (I'm assuming the loss of two threads is from the two workers threads finishing). I never get back down to 1 thread so I get stuck sleeping indefinitely. Am I missing something obvious in my code?

**The main program:**

```
from orionsdk import SwisClient
from getpass import getpass
import xlsxwriter
import signal
import threading
import queue
import sys
import time
from colorama import Fore, Style, init
from device_solarwinds_comparison import compare

init()  # init colorama
results = []

class SignalHandler:
    """
    The object that will handle signals and stop the worker threads.
    """

    #: The stop event that's shared by this handler and threads.
    stopper = None

    #: The pool of worker threads
    workers = None

    def __init__(self, stopper, workers):
        self.stopper = stopper
        self.workers = workers

    def __call__(self, signum, frame):
        # This will be called by the python signal module

        print("Telling threads to exit.")
        self.stopper.set()

        print("Waiting for threads to finish up.")
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.join()

        sys.exit(0)

class AsyncComparison(threading.Thread):
    # The queue of work
    work_queue = None

    # The event that tells the thread to stop
    stopper = None

    def __init__(self, work_queue, stopper):
        super().__init__()
        self.device_queue = work_queue
        self.id = threading.Thread.getName(self)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.stopper = stopper

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopper.is_set():
            try:
                swis_result = self.device_queue.get_nowait()
            except queue.Empty:
                break
            else:
                print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.BLUE + "[{0}]".format(self.id) + Style.RESET_ALL + "   " + Fore.GREEN + swis_result['Caption'] + Style.RESET_ALL)
                result = compare(swis_result)
                with self.lock:
                    results.append(result)
                self.device_queue.task_done()

def main():
    # Set number of worker threads
    num_workers = 2
    # Create stopper event
    stopper = threading.Event()
    # Create a work queue
    work_queue = queue.Queue()
    sw_username = 'user'
    sw_password = 'pass'

    swis = SwisClient(hostname='host', username=sw_username, password=sw_password)
    swis_results = swis.query("""SELECT TOP 2 N.Caption, N.CustomProperties.Site_Tier, N.CustomProperties.Bandwidth,
                        N.CustomProperties.Carrier, N.CustomProperties.CircuitID, N.CustomProperties.GOLDCAR,
                        N.CustomProperties.Tier1Broadband, N.CustomProperties.Tier1BroadbandSpeed, N.CustomProperties.Tier1BroadbandProvider
                        FROM Orion.Nodes N
                        WHERE N.Caption LIKE '%rt-0%'""")
    swis_results = swis_results['results']

    for result in swis_results:
        work_queue.put(result)

    # Create workers
    workers = [AsyncComparison(work_queue, stopper) for i in range(num_workers)]

    # Create our signal handler and pass it the stopper event and the workers
    handler = SignalHandler(stopper, workers)
    # Attach the SIGINT signal to our handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

    # Start the worker threads
    for i, worker in enumerate(workers):
        print(i)
        worker.start()

    # While threads are active we will sleep. Slight performance hit compared to blocking with .join
    # but this will enable the main thread to catch interrupts so we can exit with ctrl+c
    while threading.active_count() > 1:
        print("{0}".format(threading.active_count()))
        time.sleep(1)

    # Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Circuit_Comparison.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    # Add formats
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
    red_bg = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'red'})
    # Write some data headers.
    worksheet.write('A1', 'Device', bold)
    worksheet.write('B1', 'Device_CircuitID', bold)
    worksheet.write('C1', 'Device_Bandwidth', bold)
    worksheet.write('D1', 'Device_ServicePolicy', bold)
    worksheet.write('E1', 'Device_GOLDCAR', bold)
    worksheet.write('F1', 'Device_Carrier', bold)
    worksheet.write('G1', 'Device_Tier1_BB_Provider', bold)
    worksheet.write('H1', 'Device_Tier1_BB_Speed', bold)
    worksheet.write('I1', 'Solarwinds_CircuitID', bold)
    worksheet.write('J1', 'Solarwinds_Bandwidth', bold)
    worksheet.write('K1', 'Solarwinds_GOLDCAR', bold)
    worksheet.write('L1', 'Solarwinds_Carrier', bold)
    worksheet.write('M1', 'Solarwinds_Tier1_BB_Provider', bold)
    worksheet.write('N1', 'Solarwinds_Tier1_BB_Speed', bold)
    # Start from the first cell below the headers.
    row = 1
    col = 0
    print("Results:   {0}".format(results))
    for item in results:
        print(item)
        # Convert the date string into a datetime object.
        worksheet.write_string(row, col, item[0])

        if item[2] == item[3] or not item[3]:  # If bandwidth equal to service_policy, or there's no service_policy
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 2, item[2])
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 3, item[3])
        else:
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 2, item[2], red_bg)
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 3, item[3], red_bg)

        # Convert SW bandwidth to lower case, split on x, take the first number, convert to float (because of decimals)
        processed_sw_bandwidth = float(item[9].lower().split('x')[0])
        # If bandwidth is less than 100 it's probably in mbps, convert to kbps
        if processed_sw_bandwidth < 100:
            processed_sw_bandwidth *= 1000
        # If the Solarwinds bandwidth doesn't equal the device bandwidth
        # (convert float to integer to get rid of decimal then to string for comparison)
        if str(int(processed_sw_bandwidth)) != item[2]:
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 2, item[2], red_bg)
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 9, item[9], red_bg)
        else:
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 9, item[9])

        # If device goldcar not equal to Solarwinds goldcar
        if str(item[4]) != str(item[10]):
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 4, item[4], red_bg)
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 10, str(item[10]), red_bg)
        elif not str(item[4]) and str(item[10]) == 'None':  # No device Goldcar and Solarwinds reports None for Goldcar
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 4, item[4])
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 10, str(item[10]))
        else:
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 4, item[4])
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 10, str(item[10]))

        # If we're missing a circuit ID somewhere
        if  not item[8] and item[1]:
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 1, item[1], red_bg)
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 8, '', red_bg)
        elif item[8] and not item[1]:
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 1, '', red_bg)
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 8, item[8], red_bg)
        elif not item[8] and not item[1]:
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 1, '', red_bg)
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 8, '', red_bg)
        # If Solarwinds circuit ID not in the description
        elif (item[8].lower() not in item[1].lower()):
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 1, item[1], red_bg)
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 8, item[8], red_bg)
        else:
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 1, item[1])
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 8, item[8])

        # Build Carrier check list
        if item[11].lower() == 'verizon' or 'vzw':
            carrier_list = ['verizon', 'vzw']
        elif item[11].lower() == 'twt' or 'time warner telecom' or 'level3':
            carrier_list = ['twt', 'time warner telecom', 'level3']

        # If none of the carriers in carrier_list are in device description
        if all(s not in item[1].lower() for s in carrier_list):
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 1, item[1], red_bg)
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 11, item[11], red_bg)
        else:
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 1, item[1])
            worksheet.write_string(row, col + 11, item[11])

        worksheet.write_string(row, col + 5, item[5])
        worksheet.write_string(row, col + 6, item[6])
        worksheet.write_string(row, col + 7, item[7])
        worksheet.write_string(row, col + 12, item[12])
        worksheet.write_string(row, col + 13, item[13])
        row += 1

    workbook.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**The thread function:**

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import re

def compare(swis_result):
    ios_username = 'user'
    ios_password = 'pass'

    bw_re = re.compile(r'bandwidth\s(\d*)')
    desc_re = re.compile(r'description\s(.*)')
    gi02_vlan_re = re.compile(r'GigabitEthernet0\/2(\.\d*)')
    # gi02_down_re = re.compile(r'GigabitEthernet0\/2.*(down)')
    gi000_re = re.compile(r'GigabitEthernet(0\/0\/0)')
    goldcar_re = re.compile(r'VOICE-Q\n\s*priority\s(\d*)')
    servicepolicy_re = re.compile(r'service-policy\soutput\s(\d*)')
    serial_class_re = re.compile(r'class\s(\d*)')

    router = {
        'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
        'ip': swis_result['Caption'],
        'username': ios_username,
        'password': ios_password,
        'secret': ios_password,
        'port': 22,
    }
    ssh_conn = ConnectHandler(**router)
    ssh_conn.enable()

    output = ssh_conn.send_command("sh ip int br")
    try:
        gi02_vlan = re.search(gi02_vlan_re, output).group(1)
    except AttributeError:
        gi02_vlan = ''
    try:
        tier1_bb_check = re.search(gi000_re, output).group(1)
    except AttributeError:
        tier1_bb_check = ''

    while True:
        if gi02_vlan:
            output = ssh_conn.send_command("sh run int gi0/2{0}".format(gi02_vlan))
            description = re.search(desc_re, output).group(1)
            bandwidth = re.search(bw_re, output).group(1)
            service_policy = re.search(servicepolicy_re, output).group(1)
            break
        else:
            output = ssh_conn.send_command("sh run int gi0/2")
            try:
                description = re.search(desc_re, output).group(1)
                bandwidth = re.search(bw_re, output).group(1)
                try:
                    service_policy = re.search(servicepolicy_re, output).group(1)
                except AttributeError:
                    service_policy = ""
                    break
                break
            except:
                try:
                    output = ssh_conn.send_command("sh run int Multilink1")
                    description = re.search(desc_re, output).group(1)
                    bandwidth = re.search(bw_re, output).group(1)
                    service_policy = re.search(servicepolicy_re, output).group(1)
                    break
                except AttributeError:
                    try:
                        output = ssh_conn.send_command("sh run int Serial0/0/0:1")
                        description = re.search(desc_re, output).group(1)
                        bandwidth = re.search(bw_re, output).group(1)
                        output = ssh_conn.send_command("sh run int Serial0/0/0:1.1")
                        service_policy = re.search(serial_class_re, output).group(1)
                        break
                    except AttributeError:
                        description = "?"
                        bandwidth = "?"
                        service_policy = "?"
                        break

    if '01' in swis_result['Caption']:
        output = ssh_conn.send_command('sh policy-map WAN-QOS-MAP')
        goldcar = re.search(goldcar_re, output).group(1)
    else:
        goldcar = ''

    vzb_list = ['vzn', 'verizon']
    twt_list = ['time warner cable', 'twtcs']
    if any(word in description.lower() for word in vzb_list):
        carrier = 'VZB'
    elif any(word in description.lower() for word in twt_list):
        carrier = 'TWT'

    spreadsheet_row = [swis_result['Caption'], description, bandwidth, service_policy, goldcar, carrier, '', '',
                       swis_result['CircuitID'], swis_result['Bandwidth'], swis_result['GOLDCAR'], swis_result['Carrier'], '', '']
    return(spreadsheet_row)
```

Comment: If you're going to pre-fill the work queues and never add items to the queues while the workers are running, there's not much point using a queue instead of a regular list. Also, your locks aren't protecting anything.

Comment: Those class-level assignments like `workers = None` are pointless. You don't need to "declare" instance attributes or constructor parameters at class level. Those assignments are creating unused, unnecessary class attributes, a.k.a. static variables.

Comment: You have no guarantee that the libraries you're using aren't making threads of their own. `join` the threads you're interested in instead of trying to count all active threads in the entire program.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put an ssh_conn.disconnect() in the worker function to gracefully close the SSH connection. This is where the extra threads were being created that were never terminated.